# Composition in a multicategory

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic, tikz-cd

I am trying to figure out how to draw composition in a multicategory using same depiction used in Leinster's book "Higher Operads, Higher Categories".  Here is what I am trying to draw:

[image]

I did something similar, but I could not do it completely. Here is what I got

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
    \xymatrix{
      a1 \ar@{-}[r] & \ar@{-}[dd] \ar@{-}[dr]  &            & \\
      a2 \ar@{-}[r] &                          & \ar@{-}[r] & a \\
      a3 \ar@{-}[r] & \ar@{-}[ur]              &            & 
    }
\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You have tagged this with a number of apparently irrelevant tags. What does this have to do with TikZ/PGF or friends?

Answer (score 3):

[image]Here is a very similar picture that can be tweaked accordingly. In my document, all lines are adjacent to the triangles but I didn't want to include all my preamble; the positions of wires are inserted `manually' so they can easily change.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,inner=3cm,outer=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.markings,arrows.meta,calc,fit,quotes,cd,math,arrows,backgrounds,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}


\begin{displaymath}
\begin{tikzpicture}[triangle/.style = {fill=gray!20, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3}]
\path (0,0) node [triangle,draw,shape border rotate=-90,inner sep=0pt,label=178:$\vdots$] (a) {$\theta_n$} (0,4) node [triangle,draw,shape border rotate=-90,inner sep=0pt,label=178:$\vdots$] (b) {$\theta_1$} (3,2) node [triangle,draw,shape border rotate=-90,label=135:$a_1$,label=230:$a_n$,label=178:$\vdots$] (c) {$\theta$} (9,2) node [triangle,draw,shape border rotate=-90,inner sep=-25pt,label=178:$\vdots$] (d) {$\qquad\theta\circ(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n)$};
\draw [-] (a) .. controls +(right:2cm) and +(left:1cm).. (c.220);
\draw [-] (b) .. controls +(right:2cm) and +(left:1cm).. (c.140);
\draw [-] (d) to node [above] {$a$} (11.7,2);
\draw [-] (c) to node [above] {$a$} (4,2);
\draw [-] (7.2,3.5) to node [above] {$a_{11}$} (7.85,3.5);
\draw [-] (7.2,.5) to node [below] {$a_{nk_n}$} (7.85,.5);
\draw [-] (-.85,4.3) to node [above] {$a_{11}$} (-.3,4.3);
\draw [-] (-.85,3.6) to node [below] {$a_{1k_1}$} (-.3,3.6);
\draw [-] (-.85,0.3) to node [above] {$a_{n1}$} (-.3,0.3);
\draw [-] (-.85,-0.4) to node [below] {$a_{nk_n}$} (-.3,-0.4);
\node () at (5.5,2) {$\mapsto$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!