# How can i make diagrams like this in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams

[image: Composition of trees]
[image: Composition in multicategory]
[image: Composition in multicategory]

It's the composition in multicategories that i found in T. Leinster "Higher Operads, Higher Categories". At least can you tell me which package I have to use?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Can you post code showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried `tikz`?

Comment: As far as available packages go, see [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205)

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/293948/composition-in-a-multicategory), which is very similar.

Answer (score 4):

You may use [PGF/TikZ](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ) to create diagrams in Latex. There are some [tutorials](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) and [examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) in the Internet.

In the [PGF/TikZ gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) you may find examples of

- [Graphs](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/graphs/),
- [Trees](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/) and
- [Logic circuits and gates](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/circuits/).

Additionally, you may check the answers to [How to create a Hasse/Lattice Diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47392/how-to-draw-a-poset-hasse-diagram-using-tikz)

Comment: Those don't look like trees - graphs, yes, but not of the tree kind.

Answer (score 4):

In my view this question ought not be answered.

Even so, here's a demonstration of the graphs syntax provided by TikZ:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph [chain shift=(45:1), branch left, nodes={inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2.5pt, circle, fill, draw}, empty nodes, edge quotes={pos=0, auto}]
  {
    a -- ["$a^1_1$"'] b -- ["$a^2_1$"'] c [label=-45:$a^1_2$] --  { d [label=-45:$a^3_2$] , e [label=90:$a^3_2$], f [label=180:$a^3_2$]}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: graph]

Modifications and enhancements are left as an exercise for the reader.